# JS to show/hide an element based on text in an external file

Tags: javascript, content-management-system

Let me start by saying, if there is a better way to accomplish my goal, let me know.

I created a site for a restaurant. It uses a simple PHP CMS to create text files that are imported into a couple different areas of the site. One of which are the menus.

They can alter the text for the "holiday menu" link from their CMS, but when this menu should be hidden, simply deleting the text of the link (via CMS) leaves an empty clickable space.

Can I use JS to hide this link when there is no text in the external file? I've tried:

```
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "/dynamic/holiday.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (txtFile.length > 1) {  
         $('.holiday').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.holiday').hide();
    }
  }
```

and

```
 $('.holiday').each(function() {
    var len = $('.holiday').text().length  
    if(len > 1){
        $('.holiday').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.holiday').hide();
    }
});
```

Neither attempt works for reasons which will be obvious to you folks, I am sure. The 2nd one does not work because this element is always *technically* empty in HTML and the link is hidden regardless. I think.

Am I even close? Is this an overly complicated solution that should be abandoned? Your thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using PHP to create the text files from admin input but not to deliver the website's pages? If PHP is being used to deliver as well, why not do this there?

Comment: That's correct. It is an extremely rudimentary setup (probably not even worthy of being called a CMS) for a simple, mostly static website. They can add text to a few select areas for announcements, and they can upload new menus. That's pretty much it.

To answer your 2nd question: I don't know how to do that to be honest.

Comment: Okay, is this `.txt` file readable by http? As in, can you navigate to `http://yourdomain.com/dynamic/holiday.txt` in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GET` requests are malformed and incomplete. You are not calling the required `.send()` on the requests, and inside the `onreadystatechange` handler function you need to use `txtFile.responseText`, because your `txtFile` variable is actually the request, not the file itself.

But your best and easiest option, since you are using jQuery, is to use `$.ajax` or `$.get()`, because it can handle various data-types (`text` in your case) automatically:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/dynamic/holiday.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.length > 1) {  
            $('.holiday').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.holiday').hide();
        }            
    }
});
```

Comment: Like a charm. I don't think I was ever going to figure this out on my own. Thanks very much Sidd-- I'll buy you a beer anytime.